# case function for Windows buildnumbers

Tags: sql

First time on here - thanks for a great community.

I'm new to SQL query so excuse the basic question. Need some help pls.

How can i case the "BuildNumber0" to read when 9600 = 'Windows 8.1' and when 14393 = 'Windows 10 TH2'?

Here is my basic query

```
SELECT
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0,
    v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0,
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer0,
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0,
    v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 AS [OS Type],
    v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.TopConsoleUser0,
    v_R_System.User_Name0 AS [Last Logged],
    v_GS_PC_BIOS.ReleaseDate0 AS [BIOS Date],
    v_GS_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS [BIOS Version],
    v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0,
    v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0
FROM v_GS_PC_BIOS
INNER JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM ON v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID
INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID
INNER JOIN v_R_System ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_R_System.ResourceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.ResourceID
INNER JOIN v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.ResourceID
WHERE(v_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation%')
     AND (v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
    [BIOS Date];
```

Comment: Always tag your database for faster answers and comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would try this. Depending on the DBMS you are working with, there might be a bit different syntax. Cheers - Felix

```
SELECT           v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name0
               , v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0
               , v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Manufacturer0
               , v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0
               , v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Caption0 AS [OS Type]
               , v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.TopConsoleUser0
               , v_R_System.User_Name0 AS [Last Logged]
               , v_GS_PC_BIOS.ReleaseDate0 AS [BIOS Date]
               , v_GS_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS [BIOS Version]
               , v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0
               ,  CASE v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0
                    WHEN 9600 THEN 'Windows 8.1'
                    WHEN 14393 THEN 'Windows 10 TH2'
                    ELSE v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0
                  END AS B_NUM_0    
FROM            v_GS_PC_BIOS 
INNER JOIN      v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM  ON v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID = v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN      v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM  ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN      v_R_System ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_R_System.ResourceID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN      v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.ResourceID
WHERE           (v_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation%') 
AND             (v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK.FreeSpace0 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY        [BIOS Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0` in your select statement with this:

```
CASE
WHEN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0 = 9600 THEN'Windows 8.1'
WHEN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.BuildNumber0 = 14393 THEN 'Windows 10 TH2'
END
```